# Were the Airbus A320 rudder hardover issues fixed after Indonesia AirAsia Flight 8501 crashed due to uncommanded rudder deflection?

Tags: safety, airbus-a320, accident-investigation, rudder

Indonesia AirAsia Flight 8501 crashed when the rudder made an uncommanded deflection 2 degrees to the left:

> When the crew was required to fly the Airbus A320 manually, there was
> an unexplained nine-second delay between the start of the roll and
> either pilot attempting to take control. After nine seconds, the
> aircraft was banking at a 54° angle: **the rudder had deflected 2
> degrees to the left**, causing the aircraft to roll.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesia_AirAsia_Flight_8501))

I see very little discussion about the uncommanded rudder deflection, instead people were quick to blame the pilots. Was this rudder hardover issue fixed?

Comment: This was not a rudder hardover  event. Have you read the full NTSC Reoprt? http://www.aaiu.ie/sites/default/files/FRA/KNKT%20Indonesia%20Final%20Report%20PK-AXC%20Airbus%20A320-216%20Air%20Asia%20PT%20Indonesia%202015-12-01.pdf

Answer (score 4):

**Summary:** The rudder movement (not really a *hardover*, since it only moved 2°) was caused by a non-approved inflight restart of the FACs (Flight Augmentation Computers) using the circuit breakers instead of the overhead pushbuttons in an attempt to fix an issue with the Rudder Travel Limiter Units. Since these actions are not approved, there was nothing to fix, and to my knowledge nothing was changed about the A320 afterwards.

**Details:** If you look through the [final accident report](https://bea.aero/uploads/tx_elydbrapports/Final_Report_PK-AXC-reduite.pdf), you will find a detailed description of what happened to the aircraft systems. At first, the pilots successfully fixed a "AUTO FLT RUD TRV LIM SYS" ECAM message by restarting the FACs using the overhead pushbuttons:

> Between 2301 UTC to 2313 UTC the FDR and CVR recordings indicated three
> Rudder Travel Limiter Unit failures occurred and triggered the chime and master
> caution, followed by PIC actions to ECAM actions to reset FAC 1 and 2 pushbuttons on the overhead panel to OFF then to ON. Thereafter both of Rudder Travel
> Limiter Units returned to function normally.

When the ECAM message re-appeared again, the pilots pulled the circuit breakers for the FACs (which de-energizes the FACs) and then later reset them:

> At 2316:29 UTC, the FDR recorded parameters which indicate that FAC 1 was deenergized leading to the ECAM FAC 1 FAULT message associated with the 5th
> master caution. 17 seconds later the FDR recorded parameters indicate that FAC 2
> was also de-energized leading to the FAC 1+2 FAULT message associated with the
> 6
> th master caution. The FAC 1+2 FAULT was followed by rudder deflected 2° to the
> left, the aircraft flight control status reverted from Normal Law to Alternate Law and
> the Auto Pilot (A/P) and the Auto thrust (A/THR) disengaged. As consequence, the
> pilot should fly the aircraft manually.

However, resetting the circuit breakers does *not* activate the FAC again, unlike using the overhead pushbutton:

> At 2316:39 UTC, the FDR recorded that the FAC 1 was re-energized indicated by
> stopping of parameter alternation. However because the FAC1 pushbutton on
> overhead panel was not reset by put to OFF then ON, the FAC1 functions remained
> unavailable and all equipment controlled by FAC 1 did not operating.

Airbus explained why pulling the circuit breakers (in the wrong order) can lead to a movement of the rudder:

> When the 26VAC CBs of both FAC were pulled, the loss of the 26VAC was
> detected by the FAC monitoring. However the FAC logic associated to the
> computation time and rudder movement inertia created a rudder movement of about
> 2°.
>
> As both FAC were unavailable this rudder movement was not automatically
> compensated.
>
> If the 28VDC C/B is pulled before the 26VAC C/B, the FAC is immediately
> powered off and no rudder movement can be ordered.
> The rudder movement can only occur if the 26VAC C/B is pulled before the 28VDC
> C/B. The ECAM message “AUTO FLT FAC1+2 FAULT” is generated with the
> associated ECAM procedure asking to reset the FAC through the P/B on overhead
> panel.
>
> After the FAC2 26VAC and 28VDC CBs have been pushed, there is no more rudder
> trim function available as no FAC was reset through the P/B on overhead panel. The
> message “AUTO FLT FAC1+2 FAULT” was still displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Roll was only an effect of a fully developed stall. The rudder did not go hardover. Air Asia 8501 did not crash due to uncommanded rudder deflection.

> I see very little discussion about the uncommanded rudder deflection.

That's because it was not the issue and the rudder worked in alternate law, the problem was: recovering from a fully developed stall. From [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/37534) answer:

> The Air Asia captain did realise they were in a fully developed stall, and immediately pitched the stick forward. He was an ex military pilot. The issue there was:
>
> - Language. An Indonesian national using English to instruct the French co-pilot to Push Back.
> - No direct force cue that the copilot was pitching back while the captain was correctly pitching forward. Airbus averages out conflicting stick inputs if no pilot has taken exclusive control by pressing the override button > 20 seconds.

A cracked solder joint in one of the printed circuit board had caused a repeated malfunction in the rudder system, which the pilots attemted to cure by pulling circuit breakers, causing the autopilot to disengage.

Answer (score 1):

The AirAsia crash was not a flight control or an aircraft design issue.

The crew disabled multiple flight control computers in flight trying to resolve a minor (but persistent) computer issue the aircraft had. As a result of computers being shutdown simultaneously, the aircraft reverted into what is called an Alternate Law which caused autopilot to disconnect and aircraft to deviate from intended flight path. For some reason nobody was monitoring the flight instruments (ie. looking forward) while the computer reset was being attempted. The reason might be that the circuit breaker panel is located behind copilot's seat. At the time the captain had left his seat to perform the reset and the copilot was supposed to be flying the aircraft.

"Pilot error" is a quick blame for pilots who were startled with unforeseen situation. As usual, you can go deeper and ask why licensed pilots made the said mistakes. The fundamentals of the crash are not unlike that of the famous Eastern Air Lines crash. In both cases a very survivable technical issue led to an accident because of poor CRM, which can be attributed to insufficient training and procedures, as identified in the final report.